# How to transform table using complex sql query while loading data from CSV into database within a spring boot application

Tags: sql, database, spring-boot

I have a CSV that i am loading into a spring boot application database, so that the data can be delivered by an API. After loading it into the database, I need to run some SQL on the table to `create a new column` so that it can be in the proper form for the API.

It is unclear to me how to run a query for a new column, such as

```
select 
    t.*,
    cumulative 
        - lag(cumulative, 1, 0) over(partition by city order by date) as difference
from mytable t
```

on this table before running the API. Im relatively new to spring boot and would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction. Ive done a lot of googling and couldn't find anything similar to this. I did see some stuff about `data.sql` but it sounds like that might not work.

---

Im wondering how people do this professionally? What is the best way to load and transform this data? It looks like Spring batch could be helpful but I would like someone to help point me down the right path.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can create a *view*:

```
create view v_mytable as
    select t.*,
           (cumulative  -
            lag(cumulative, 1, 0) over (partition by city order by date)
           ) as difference
    from mytable t;
```

You can then use `v_mytable` just as you would a table name in your application.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm having trouble figuring out where I can put this SQL and how to get it to execute after loading the data in within my spring boot application?

Comment: @JacFrall . . . You do this in the database.  Then the application will see `v_mytable` just as it would a table.

Comment: Ah, that makes much more sense than doing it in the java code. Could you point me in the direction of automating SQL queries to run on a database? I have very basic database experience and after googling I didn't see much on this, probably because Im searching the wrong words

Comment: @JacFrall . . . This does not need to be automated.  When you create the table that you load data into, you can create the view.  It persists.

Comment: This spring boot applicaiton pulls data from an API and updates a database, it fetches new data once a day. This new data needs to be transformed using the above query. I'm looking to get spring boot to do this form me so I don't have to manually mess with the data every day. I figured there would be some way to run a SQL command on the table at specific times triggered by spring boot